# Gravit designer theme for inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Anyone know if there exists a theme / skin that make inkscape look like Gravit designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't even possible with current Inkscape versions (i.e. Inkscape 0.92.3).

(However, you can adjust the keyboard mapping in Edit > Preferences > Interface > Keyboard Shortcuts, and some configuration will be possible in the next major Inkscape version).